# How do I use the Bootstrap theme carousel?

Tags: 8, theming

The Bootstrap Carousel locates in the following folder. As I know, in Drupal 7, I could use Bootstrap Carousel in a view. In Drupal 8, how could I leverage this plugin in my website?

bootstrap -> src -> Plugin -> Preprocess -> BootstrapCarousel.php

```
class BootstrapCarousel extends PreprocessBase implements PreprocessInterface
```

Comment: check this https://www.reddit.com/r/drupal/comments/3xenmg/bootstrap_carousel_alternatives_for_drupal_8/